# dojo/request/iframe does not clean up form when timeout is exceeded

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

I am using `iframe()` to return a generated file from the server. I noticed that subsequent calls to `iframe()` after the first request were not returning at all so I added `timeout` onto the options. This is now causing the form data that gets injected into the iframe to never get cleaned up after the timeout is exceeded.

This behavior is reproduced here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shoe788/xq509n4j/)

```
require(["dojo/request/iframe"], function(iframe){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        iframe("http://posttestserver.com/post.php", {
            data: { test:123 },
            timeout: 100
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

Running and inspecting shows 10 forms with the injected data present as html inputs. If you remove the timeout option all elements are cleaned. If you increase the timeout to a very high number all the elements are cleaned. It seems only when the timeout is exceeded do the elements persist.

Possible workarounds that I am considering are...

1. Clean up manually after timeout exceeded.
2. Configure options differently so this never happens. Not sure if this is possible.
3. Use something else other than an iframe. Not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the jsFiddle example, it is not allowing to load the 'google.com' because 'X-Frame-Options' is set to 'SAMEORIGIN''.

I have added a sample pdf of download, you can check the browser console/network tab. All the 10 requests are getting succeed. Also the forms inside the iframe gets cleared up.

Please find the updated jsFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/kLLvkm6k/4/

```js
require(["dojo/request/iframe"], function(iframe){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      iframe("http://www.analysis.im/uploads/seminar/pdf-sample.pdf", {
       data: { test:123 }
      });
    }
});
```

Thanks
-Srikant

Comment: But as you've just demonstrated, no file is being returned to download.

Comment: Yes you are right, this just shows that the browser is actually getting the response from the server. If the file type is xml/json/html we can easily handle through the iframe. But considering your scenario of downloading a file it better to go with other javascript options like using an anchor tag to link your pdf file or just show the pdf in a iframe(pdf viewer).

Comment: I dont have a problem getting a response from the server. Actually if you replace the url with anything that will accept a cross-x post you'll see the same behavior. Linking to a document doesn't work for me, since the file is generated dynamically.

Comment: Hi Shoe, as you mentioned you have already code for getting the response as an attachment/stream then its should be easy to attach it an iframe without using the dojo requests..           EX:                  <iframe id='container'> </iframe>
<a href='' target='container' onclick="document.getElementById('container').src = 'http://www.analysis.im/uploads/seminar/pdf-sample.pdf'; return false;"> download </a>                                                                                                        here you can set the actual service (which return the pdf) as the src for the iframe